# Error while connecting Cloudant DB from my local Spark cluster(PySpark) using spark-cloudant connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudant

```
    I am getting the following error while connecting Cloudant DB from my local Spark cluster(PySpark) using spark-cloudant connector.

    The spark-cloudant connector is: https://spark-packages.org/package/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant

    I am started my PySpark with following command,
    pyspark2.cmd --jars "all jars for spark-cloudant connector"

The code I am using, 
sqlContextNew = SQLContext(sc)
booksDataDF = sqlContextNew.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").option("cloudant.host","AAA-HOST").option("cloudant.username", "BBB-USERNAME"). option("cloudant.password","CCC-PASSWORD").load("booksdata")
```

The error message is: 
16/07/22 23:01:51 INFO JsonStoreDataAccess: reuse SparkEnv ActorSystem as it contains spray
16/07/22 23:01:52 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriverActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriverActorSystem]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$ArrowAssoc$.extension$$minus$greater(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Tuple2
        at org.parboiled.scala.Parser$class.rule(Parser.scala:73)
        at org.parboiled.scala.Parser$class.rule(Parser.scala:46)
        at spray.http.parser.HttpParser$.rule(HttpParser.scala:29)
        at spray.http.parser.CORSHeaders$class.$timesAccess$minusControl$minusMax$minusAge(CORSHeaders.scala:59)
        at spray.http.parser.HttpParser$.$timesAccess$minusControl$minusMax$minusAge(HttpParser.scala:29)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error is because of the wrong Scala version. What is the scala version you are using? For both, spark and spark-cloudant you need Scala 2.10.

Comment: Hi @Mayya Sharipova, Spark version I am using is spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6(Scala 2.10). The spark-cloudant connector version is spark-cloudant-1.6.2-s_2.10.jar. I am wondering what is happening, let me know if you have some other point to check. I will try the same. Thanks for your update.

Comment: @PariMargu What is Scala version installed on your computer?

Comment: Hi @Mayya Sharipova, Scala version 2.10.5 is installed in my computer.